# try to get my cfdiv to load on the same page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a page that provide some information and a `cfselect` tag.

```
    <cfform name="selectrate" method="post" format="html">
      <cfselect name="rateid" query="getrate" value="rateid" display="ratecode" />

    </cfform>
   <cfajaximport tags="cfform">
      <cfdiv id="rateDiv" bind="url:testniva_3.cfm?rateid={rateid}" style="height:1500" bindonload="true">
```

For each `rateid` that is selected the `cfdiv` will call on testniva_3.cfm which provide information for that `rateid`. The testniva_3.cfm has a `<cfsavecontent>` tag that will calculate the `grandtotal` for the `cfgrid` in the same page. The testniva_3.cfm has this code:

```
   <cfform name="display" format="flash">
            <cfgrid name= "cart" query="getdtls" selectmode="edit"  width="580">
            <cfgridcolumn name="chargename" header="Charge Type" dataalign="right" select="No" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="price" header="price"type="numeric"  dataalign="right" select="No" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="quantity" header="Quantity" type="numeric"  dataalign="right"  >               
        </cfgrid>

    <cfinput type="Button" name="calculateBtn" value="Calculate Order" onclick="#calculateTotal#">
    <cfinput type="Text" name="total" disabled="true" label="Total $" size="5">
    </cfform>
```

The `cfdiv` seems to bind with the `cfselect` tag, because when I change the option in `cfselect`, the data in testniva_3.cfm page also changes, however, instead of remain on the page with all the information and the select option, it give me an error: `Error processing JavaScript in markup for element rateDiv: [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information`
then when I click OK, it refreshs the page and just give me the testniva_3.cfm page without all the information and select option of the main page. If I change the format of the `cfgrid` on the `cfform` in the testniva_3.cfm page to html, then the grid refresh the data without any problem, however, my `<cfsavecontent>#calculateTotal#` will not work with html format.

I am not sure what went wrong, and how to fix it. Any one have any ideas? I would really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Stop using `cfselect`, `cfform` and `cfdiv` (or any other UI components in ColdFusion). Learn how to do this the right way using a JS library (or libraries) such as jQuery. Using the UI stuff in ColdFusion will always lead to issues and the skill is not transferable to other technologies, however, using juery is.

Comment: [Ben Forta blog - When Using ColdFusion Client Technologies No Longer Makes Sense](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense)